# flash not displaying properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: flash, adobe, cross-browser

i'm embedding a flash swf with this following code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="800" height="600"> 
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.namenecklacesdirect.co.uk/font-preview-tool/flashvar_as3.swf" /> 
    <param name="flashvars" value="my_flashvar=black" /> 
    <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
    <embed src="http://www.namenecklacesdirect.co.uk/font-preview-tool/flashvar_as3.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="585" flashvars="my_flashvar=black"></embed> 
</object>
```

it is working fine on all the browsers but in internet explorer it doesn't display properly 
there is an additional left margin or something.
here is the screen shots:

as seen in IE:

http://bayimg.com/hAJHKAaDg

as seen on other bowsers:

http://bayimg.com/hAJhjaadg

can anybody help me please
Thanks in advance

PS:I haven'used any javascript css or nething else the html file contains this plain code only

Comment: Can you please post any other HTML or CSS that is used on the page?

Comment: The Aaron has it right, you need CSS to turn off the default settings in IE.

Comment: why not use swfobject to embed your swf?

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from a reset.css in your page, as I.E. is a niggly so and so it sometimes looks a lot different than other browsers. This is the reset I would normally use:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

This should make it look a bit better, if that doesn't work, you're going to need a seperate css file for internet explorer.

Comment: haven'used any javascript css or nething else the html file contains this plain code only

Comment: then that is why there is no styling to it, which is why it will just display differently in each browser, you need a css if you wanna sort that, or at least some HTML styling.

Answer (score 0):

i just noticed that your width and height do not match up between embedding for IE and other browsers. as well give this a shot, after your height, add in this :
    align="middle" or left, right